# How to use DbModelBuilder with Database First Approach to implement Soft Delete

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement a soft delete in our EF 6 project. We are using the database first approach and I noticed that you cannot override `OnModelCreating`.

When using the Code-First approach it's possible to apply a global filter for a particular entity as described in this [blog post](https://putshello.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/entity-framework-soft-deletes-are-easy/#gist14000410).

How can I recreate this using the Database First approach?

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false))
            .Ignore(m => m.IsDeleted);
    }
}
```

Comment: A work-around would be to use a SQL View to filter out the soft-deleted records.  Then use the View as your database-first model.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false))
            .Ignore(m => m.IsDeleted);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

You need to write the base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); build you query & i have also highlighted line in the post.

Answer (score 0):

There is need to define a constructor in this form before performing your actions:

```
public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public virtual DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false))
            .Ignore(m => m.IsDeleted);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using database first approach you don't need to add OnModelCreating for IsDeleted flag. You can handle, when you write custom SaveChanges method. Don't forget to ChangeTracker must be open.

For example;

```
public int SaveChanges(){
    var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries();
    foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(c => c.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)){
        var info = entry.Entity.GetType()
                    .GetProperty("IsDeleted", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
if ( info!=null && info.CanWrite){
    info.SetValue(entry.Entity, false, null);
}
}
base.SaveChanges();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach to standardize soft deleting entities, explained below step-by-step.

**1-** Create ISoftDelete interface:

```
public interface ISoftDelete
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

**2-** Then create your entities you want to implement soft-delete approach.

```
public class Company : ISoftDelete
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

**3-** Change state of entity from "Deleted" to "Modified" by overriding DBContext.SaveChanges() method something like below.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Deleted))
        TryCancelDeletion(entry);

    return base.SaveChanges();
}

private bool TryCancelDeletion(EntityEntry entry)
{
    if (!(entry.Entity is ISoftDelete))
        return false;

    entry.Reload();
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    ((ISoftDelete)entry.Entity).IsDeleted = true;
    return true;
}
```

Soft-delete entities are not actually deleted, marked as IsDeleted = true in the database, but can not be retrieved to the application normally.

You should apply default filters for exclude soft-deleted entities from results.